# Cookies are blocked on wp-admin Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I enter the /wp-admin area, and then, after smashing the username and password down, I get the: "Error: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress."

I have tried almost every "solution" on the Edited the wp-config - the functions.php file, etc. Nothing is working. Tried Chrome, Firefox, even Internet Explorer !?..., tried to delete ALL caching/content on my browser, not helping..

I have never had this kind of problem before.

Please guide me :)

Comment: Can you check request and response? Are cookies transiting at least? It may be a simple PHP or Apache misconfiguration, but it would be better for you to give us more background on what's the server you're using and what are the contents of your .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks for reply @anatoli, Already I have two websites in same hosting, One website working fine another website is getting error

Comment: Do you have some different plugins installed on the non-working one?

Comment: I have using different plugin

Comment: Set cookies not working

Comment: Any chance for you to share .htaccess contents?

Comment: Thanks for reply @anatoli issues is fixed,  problem is .htaccess file

Comment: I have deleted the code for the htaccess file

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
Header set no-cache '1'
Header set Set-Cookie 'NO_CACHE=1; path=/;'
Header set Cache-Control 'max-age=31536000, public'
</ifModule>
now problem is fixed

Answer (score 2):

I have deleted the code from htaccess file,
`<ifModule mod_headers.c>`
Header set Connection keep-alive Header set no-cache `1` Header set Set-Cookie `NO_CACHE=1; path=/;` Header set Cache-Control `max-age=31536000, public`

now problem is fixed